# Given a geodesic $I$ and a point $p$ not on $I$, there is a point $q$ on $I$ such that the geodesic joining $p$ and $q$ meets $I$ orthogonally.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

The theorem I want to prove is this

> Given a geodesic $I$ in hyperbolic space and a point $p$ not on $I$, there is a unique point $q$ on $I$ such that the geodesic joining $p$ and $q$ meets $I$ orthogonally.

I'm working inside $D$ (Poincaré disk model). I already received some advice, which is to consider some arbitrary geodesic while taking $p$ to be at the origin. I've drawn a picture which shows this idea; the geodesic $I$ is the semi-circle, and $p$ is the point at the origin not on $I$. The geodesic straight line through the origin joins $p$ and $q$, and clearly meets $I$ orthogonally.

[image]

My question is, how can I generalise this result to conclude that it's true for all points $p$ outside the geodesic?

As far as I understand, Möbius transformations map geodesics to geodesics and also act transitively on pairs (and triples) of points. I also know that Möbius transformations preserve angles, so if I map these two geodesics to two others the orthogonality will be preserved. I think I should use this information but don't how know to put it together.

Comment: You have it. Given any geodesic $\gamma$ and point $p'\in\gamma$, there is an isometry carrying your diameter to $\gamma$ and $p$ to $p'$. (You can do this directly thinking about how where three points go determines a unique Möbius transformation. Or you can use the fact that the isometry group acts transitively on pairs $(p,v)$ of points and tangent vectors at the point.)

Comment: Say I apply the isometry that takes the diameter to the geodesic $\gamma$, and $p$ to $p'$. Does this mean the geodesic $\gamma$ and the geodesic going through $q$ meet orthogonally as before? I thought that I would have to apply the transformation to both geodesics in my picture in order to preserve the angle, not just apply it to the diameter.

Comment: Well, I used the geodesic through $p$ to determine *which* isometry (or Möbius transformation) to use. It acts on the whole hyperbolic plane, of course, and so it carries $q$ to $q'$ and the other geodesic to an appropriate geodesic through $q'$, all the while preserving angles (because it's an isometry).

Comment: Ah it makes sense now; I just started learning about isometries so some basic things are still going over my head. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: My pleasure. Keep learning.

Comment: This seems sorted out now. Does one of you, Ted or Jake, want to write this up as an answer?